# Parcel - Invalid Config from config-default?

Tags: reactjs, parceljs

Hi everyone! 

Recently I'm running into an error when trying to run my React app in Parcel that says I have an invalid config for the compressor, but I haven't changed anything from the default configurations. I've tried reinstalling but the same error occurs. 
Here's the error I'm getting:

```
@parcel/core: Invalid Parcel Config

node_modules/@parcel/config-default/index.json:149:2
  148 |   },
> 149 |   "compressors": {
>     |   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Possible values: "extends", "validators", "filePath", "resolveFrom"
  150 |     "*": [
  151 |       "@parcel/compressor-raw"
```

This is what is in the index.json for @parcel:

```
"compressors": {
  "*": [
  "@parcel/compressor-raw"
  ]
},
```

I've tried searching for this as a bug, but didn't find any results? 
 Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what worked for me:

1. Remove this `"@parcel/transformer-sass": "^2.0.0-rc.0"` dev dependency from package.json file if it is there and delete the node_module folder.
2. Run this command to install dependencies: `npm install`
3. Run this command to install Parcel and Parcel/transformer-sass: `npm install --save-dev parcel @parcel/transformer-sass`
4. In package.json file, change the line `"main": "src/index.html"`, to `"source": "src/index.html"`. In the same file,  add the following scripts in the scripts. `"start": "parcel", "build": "parcel build"`
5. In the index.html file, add this type="module" attribute to the script tag. e.g. `<script type="module" src="index.jsx"></script>`
6. After this, use the start script to start the app. e.g. `npm run start`